# Cannot connect internet in centos 6.3 minimal version

Tags: centos6, windows-server-2012, hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2, apache-cloudstack

I have a windows server 2012 R2 machine on which i am using hyper-v.I have installed Centos 6.3 minimal in a virtual machine.Now i am not able to connect to the internet.I have a file /etc.../ifcfg-lo  with default config but when i do change the file to the new config of the windows server network config it still shows the old config and not the new config which i have changed and also there is no eth0 which google says me to create.

I have already tried to change the configuration of the /etc/.../ifcfg-lo file to the setting of the network adapter setting in windows server 2012 R2

Answer (score 1):

lo is the loopback device, and you should NOT change that config file.

I would very much recommend using using a more recent version of centos as 6.3 is quite old. There were a number of hyperv features added in 6.4, and several fixes in the following 6.5 and 6.6 versions. Please see -> https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/6.4_Release_Notes/virtualization.html, which shows the added functionality (including networking)

Also http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531026.aspx might be worth a look, as it details the support matrix for various versions. (It shows 6.3 as needing additional drivers available from microsoft).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but the it team in the company has downloaded oly 6.3 minimal version although i told the latest version so i wanted some suggestion on the internet connection in the 6.3 version oly pls help